# Java web framework with Jazzy UI

Tags: jquery, spring, html, spring-mvc

I am evaluating technology for my web project. The web site should work in all modern PC browsers and smartphones (Android, iOS, BB).The requirement is the UI should be Rich like Flash, Silverlight and the data will be exposed in Java REST services.

Which is the best framework to choose?

1. GWT with HTML5, Spring
2. HTML5, jQuery, Backbone.js
3. JSP with HTML5, Spring
4. HTML5, jQuery, Spring (is this combination possible?)

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Removed the text 'Jazzy'

Comment: Are we talking zoot suit jazzy or black polo neck jazzy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of these are overly flash-like by themselves.

GWT provides you with some fancy widgets, but so does jQueryUI.  There's no simple way to make a website look pretty besides getting a good designer to do so.  HTML5 and CSS3 provide you with a lot of tools to make your websites look pretty snappy, take a look into CSS3 transitions and such to get a feel for what I'm talking about.

As for the actual frameworks, I'd use Spring MVC as your REST service, JSP as your view technology, the rest is just sugar.

If you want a single page website, that's purely Ajax driven, definitely use backbone.js, with it you can avoid most of the MVC architecture of spring, and decouple your view layer completely from your service layer which is quite nice.

Just my 2c